# IoS Cocoa fill area with given color

Tags: ios, cocoa, uikit, quartz-graphics, appkit

I try to color given area of bitmap. After show it on screen. 
Currently I use following approach: 
There are representing bitmap `CGContextRef` and two-dimensional array of bits - by which we know which pixel to color. Then a loop throw this array and drawing an ellipse:

```
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
        if(colormask[i][j] == 1){
            CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(i, j, 1, 1);
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(bitmap, red, green, blue, 1.0);
            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(bitmap, circleRect);
        }
    }
 }
```

This solves the problem but works too slow. Please provide any other idea. Maybe there is solution using Quartz?

Comment: May I know which image you want color. just tag a simple image here and tell which portion you want color.. so that we can help you..

Comment: This is any black and white image as for instance in kids coloring books. Then I want to color certain domain of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Flood fill Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) for coloring the image it will be very fast and efficient. Objective-c version of flood fill Algorithm is [Here](https://github.com/OgreSwamp/ObjFloodFill/blob/master/src/FloodFill.m).

Comment: Yes and I already implemented this algorithm. By I founded by your link great idea how to color domain - I just need to set appropriate bytes of bitmap data like this:


`code`
               int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * y) + x * bytesPerRow/width;
                rawData[byteIndex] = red;
                rawData[byteIndex+1] = blue;
                rawData[byteIndex+2] = green;
`code`
And this works really fast! So my problem is solved. Thank you. :)

Comment: Can I find basic example of its implementation anywhere? or step by step process to include it in your project?